# Webpage Messages Change Based on Browser

Tags: browser, opera

[image: Screenshot]

I got this message when I tried to use Yahoo! Answers in Opera (Was checking browser support for my page, and wanted to search some stuff up.) I don`t get this message in my default browser (Chrome), nor in Internet Explorer, or Firefox.

So, I was wondering, is it possible to change part of a webpage, based on the browser a person is using? (By the way, the image was too large, so it was rather heavily cropped.) And is the solution available with simple web programming? (i.e. HTML or CSS, or basic Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the browser and various other bits of information using some javascript.

Quirks Mode has a pretty nice article on how this can be achieved: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Once you detect the browser, you can then use javascript to modify the HTML and CSS.

---

Having said that, browser detection is discouraged and should rarely be used. Instead, you could consider feature detection using a library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

In feature detection, instead of detecting the browser, you detect to see if a certain feature you want to use is supported by the browser. If not, Modernizr might provide a polyfill which emulates the feaure. If a polyfill is not available, then you fullback to a baseline implementation.

Feature detection is much better, because:

- users can turn features on and off in browsers.
- There are so many browsers and variants that it's very very difficult to catch everything with browser detection.

Comment: Because it's hard to tell what's happening without seeing any code. In other words, show us what you have tried :)

Comment: I managed to get it working, there were some syntax errors in the document, but how can I get a specific browser? appCodeName returns "Mozilla" in most Opera, IE, Chrome and firefox, and appName returns "Netscape" in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari.